# Install Unity 3d Without X

Tags: ubuntu, x-server, headless

I'm trying to setup Jenkins to work with Unity3d for CI of a game I'm developing.

However, I can't work out how to install Unity3d without using the Hub which needs an X Server.

I'd rather not install an X server to do this and given that Unity has a headless mode I'd assume there's a way to do this.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

## Answer:

You can get `apt` to ignore certain dependencies. Try this:

`sudo apt install <packagename> xorg-server-` (or whatever the dependency is called)

Note the `-` at the end of `xorg-server`. That means to exclude that package from installing.

Source: https://serverfault.com/questions/250224/how-do-i-get-apt-get-to-ignore-some-dependencies/859394

Edit: Only do this if `xorg-server` is not required by Unity 3D. You may not need it, but Unity 3D might.

Edit 2: If it turns out you DO need that extra dependency, then just `sudo apt install` it later.

Hope this helps!